# client denied by server configuration

Tags: apache, kohana-3, virtualhost

I try to setup kohana 3 project as virtual host.

Config:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  DocumentRoot "D:/Devel/matysart/matysart_dev1"
  ServerName matysart-one.local
  ServerAlias www.matysart-one.local
  DirectoryIndex index.php
</VirtualHost>
```

Error (403):

> [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration:
>   D:/Devel/matysart/matysart_dev1/

Could somebody help?

Comment: This error will only occur if: the client address matches 127.0.0.0/8 or the client address is ::1 or both the client and the server address of the connection are the same.  This is a new feature that was added to Apache 2.4.

In short if you are testing this on your local host make sure this flag "Require local" is set.  It is not however needed for your production server

Comment: possible duplicate of [Apache2: 'AH01630: client denied by server configuration'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18392741/apache2-ah01630-client-denied-by-server-configuration)

Answer (score 108, accepted):

In my case, I modified directory tag.

**From**

```
<Directory "D:/Devel/matysart/matysart_dev1">
  Allow from all
  Order Deny,Allow
</Directory>
```

**To**

```
<Directory "D:/Devel/matysart/matysart_dev1">
  Require local
</Directory>
```

And it seriously worked. It's seems changed with Apache 2.4.2.

Comment: where did you find that tag? did you need to add it to a file?

Comment: It's not a bug. It's a feature. I found somewhere from there http://httpd.apache.org/docs/

Comment: Just built a new machine with the latest copy of xampp.  All the virtual hosts stopped working.  Require local fixed it.

Comment: This got me too using 2.4, `Require local` fixed it... guess RTM?

Comment: I had a better experience with "Require all granted".

Comment: This is [documented as part of the Apache Module mod_authz_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_host.html#reqlocal)

Comment: It is a required step when upgrading to Apache 2.4. See http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/upgrading.html#run-time

Comment: Actually ["Require all granted" is documented as replacement for "Allow from all"](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#reqall)

Answer (score 37):

For me the following worked which is copied from example in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`:

```
<Directory /srv/www/default>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

`Require all granted` option is the solution for the first problem example in [wiki.apache.org](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration) page dedicated for this issue for Apache version 2.4+.

More details about Require option can be found on [official apache page for mod_authz module](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_authz_core.html#require) and on [this page too](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_authz_host.html). Namely:

> Require all granted -> Access is allowed unconditionally.

Comment: This worked on my local installation /home/userx/Development/site

Answer (score 21):

The error "client denied by server configuration" generally means that somewhere in your configuration are `Allow from` and `Deny from` directives that are preventing access.  Read the [mod_authz_host](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_authz_host.html) documentation for more details.

You should be able to solve this in your VirtualHost by adding something like:

```
<Location />
  Allow from all
  Order Deny,Allow
</Location>
```

Or alternatively with a `Directory` directive:

```
<Directory "D:/Devel/matysart/matysart_dev1">
  Allow from all
  Order Deny,Allow
</Directory>
```

Some investigation of your Apache configuration files will probably turn up default restrictions on the default DocumentRoot.

Comment: For me the following worked which is copied from example in `/etc/apache2/apache2.conf`: `       <Directory /srv/www/default>
               Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
               AllowOverride None
               Require all granted
       </Directory>
`

Comment: For me it was `Require all granted` that got it.

Answer (score 6):

in my case,

i'm using macOS Mojave (Apache/2.4.34). There was an issue in virtual host settings at /etc/apache2/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf file. after adding the required directory tag my problem was gone.

Require all granted

Hope the full virtual host setup structure will save you.

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot "/Users/vagabond/Sites/MainProjectFolderName/public/"
    ServerName project.loc

    <Directory /Users/vagabond/Sites/MainProjectFolderName/public/>
        Require all granted
    </Directory>

    ErrorLog "/Users/vagabond/Sites/logs/MainProjectFolderName.loc-error_log"
    CustomLog "/Users/vagabond/Sites/logs/MainProjectFolderName.loc-access_log" common
</VirtualHost>
```

all you've to do replace the MainProjectFolderName with your exact ProjectFolderName.

Answer (score 1):

this worked for me..

```
<Location />
 Allow from all
 Order Deny,Allow
</Location>
```

I have included this code in my /etc/apache2/apache2.conf

Answer (score -1):

I have servers with proper lists of hosts and IPs. None of that `allow all` stuff. My fix was to put the hostname of my new workstation into the list. So the advise is:

**Make sure the computer you're using is ACTUALLY on the list of allowed IPs.** Look at IPs from logmessages, resolve names, check `ifconfig` / `ipconfig` etc.

*Google sent me due to the error-message.