# php session login script not working on UniServ installed on local server

Tags: php, mysql, session, authentication

I have a login script which is working fine on the production server hosted on shared hosting (Windows8 server).

The same script when tried on the local server(not connected to internet) which is WindowsXP and UniServ (like XAMPP OR WAMP). It just gives a blank screen.

So I tried testing a few scripts if there is any issue in Apache / Mysql / PHP. All 3 are working fine on Uniserv.

I tried checking the configuration for session path, all that is fine. 
Not sure what else needs to be checked if the same files have to work on local server. Need help.

Please check the below login script:

```
    <?php // accesscontrol.php
    include_once 'common.php';
    include_once 'db2.php';

    session_start();

    $uid = isset($_POST['uid']) ? $_POST['uid'] : $_SESSION['uid'];
    $pwd = isset($_POST['pwd']) ? $_POST['pwd'] : $_SESSION['pwd'];

    if(!isset($uid)) {
      ?>
      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C/DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
    <title>Test - Login</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
          content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
    <head>
    <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    .style1 {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .style3 {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }

    body {
        background-color: #D7F0FF;
        margin-left: 0px;
        margin-top: 0px;
        margin-right: 0px;
        margin-bottom: 0px;
    }

    -->
    </style>

      </head>
    <body>
      <h1 class="style1"> <br><br>Testing Login Required </h1>
      <span class="style3"><br>
      You <strong>must login to access this area </strong>of the site. <br>
      <br>
      If you are not a registered user, please contact your Admin
         to sign up for instant access!</span>
      <p><form method="post" action="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">

        <span class="style3">User ID:&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;    
        <input type="text" name="uid" size="12" />
        <br>
        <br />
        Password:</span>    
        <input type="password" name="pwd" SIZE="12" />
        <br>
        <br />
        <input type="submit" value="Login" />
      </form></p>

    </body>
      </html>
      <?php
      exit;
    }

    $_SESSION['uid'] = $uid;
    $_SESSION['pwd'] = $pwd;

    dbConnect("exceltron");
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE
            userid = '$uid' AND password = '$pwd'";
    $result = mysql_query($sql);
    if (!$result) {
      error('A database error occurred while checking your '.
            'login details.\\nIf this error persists, please '.
            'contact you@example.com.');
    }

    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
      unset($_SESSION['uid']);
      unset($_SESSION['pwd']);
      ?>

      <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C/DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"
        "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
      <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
      <head>
        <title> Access Denied </title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type"
          content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />
        <style type="text/css">
    <!--
    .style1 {
        font-size: 16px;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    .style3 {
        font-size: 12px;
        font-family: Verdana, Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
    -->
    </style>  

      </head>
      <body>
      <br/>
      <br/>

      <h1 class="style1"> Access Denied </h1>
      <p class="style3">Your user ID or password is incorrect, or you are not a
         registered user on this site. To try logging in again, click
         <a href="<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>">here</a>. To access, please contact our Admin !</a>.</p>
      </body>
      </html>
      <?php
      exit;
    }

    $username = mysql_result($result,0,'fullname');
    $_SESSION['user'] = mysql_result($result,0,'userid');
    ?>
```

db.php:

```
    <?php // db2.php this is only for accesscontrol.php

    $dbhost = 'localhost';
    $dbuser = 'exceltron';
    $dbpass = '********';

    function dbConnect($db='') {
        global $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass;

        $dbcnx = @mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass)
            or die('The site database appears to be down.');

        if ($db!='' and !@mysql_select_db($db))
            die('The site database is unavailable.');

        return $dbcnx;
    }
    ?>
```

common.php

```
    <?php // common.php

    function error($msg) {
        ?>
        <html>
        <head>
        <script language="JavaScript">
        <!--
            alert("<?=$msg?>");
            history.back();
        //-->
        </script>
        </head>
        <body>
        </body>
        </html>
        <?
        exit;
    }
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turn error reporting on and look into error logs and check phpinfo() whats interesting there.

Comment: I have checked the log and this is the line: [Tue Feb 26 15:56:19.646495 2013] [access_compat:error] [pid 3864:tid 584] [client 172.166.0.212:2618] AH01797: client denied by server configuration: C:/UniServer/www/       ---- What next?

Comment: It has nothing to do with PHP script, just wrong Apache settings. Here are few links from google. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413042/client-denied-by-server-configuration http://wiki.apache.org/httpd/ClientDeniedByServerConfiguration

Comment: Thank you so much for the help, I just did one small change in both files - added 'php' after <? and it worked just fine.

Comment: For all out there who are working on UniServ, pl make sure <?php is in all your php files.

Comment: I noticed it and wanted to tell u, but thought it wont be a problem before you post the error log :D good luck! :)