# apache: client denied by server configuration - but _which_ rule?

Tags: apache

Apache's log file says:

```
[Thu May 30 14:57:51 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /path/to/file
```

How do I find the configuration that causes this?

I would have loved if Apache had said:

```
[Thu May 30 14:57:51 2013] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] client denied by server configuration: /path/to/file due to /etc/apache/config.file:44:  Deny from all
```

So what I would like to have is a general useful way of determining the config file denying the access and the line number (or the directory that has the missing permission - if the error is caused by file system permissions). I am aware that there may be more files causing the denial, but a solution giving the first one will be accepted, too.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413042/client-denied-by-server-configuration

Comment: Does not help. It does not deal with setup involving multiple config file and .htaccess files.

Comment: Doesn't it say "/etc/apache/config.file:44"? so in line 44 in that file i'd assume. i faced that problem many times and the solution was always "Allow from all" "Require all granted"

Comment: No. The first log entry is what Apache actually logs. The second entry is what I would have loved it to log (but, sadly, it does not). If your version of Apache does the second type of logging, please show how to make Apache do that.

Comment: I see, sorry for not taking the time to read it properly.

Comment: Well you can't edit that error output directly without editing the apache source, but changing "LogLevel" to something more sensitive than "warning" should give you more output. but that would be good for debugging not for long-term log keeping.