# XAMPP Apache error: client denied by server configuration

Tags: php, xampp

I just started up my computer and Apache in XAMPP no longer works. I suspect is has something to do with the fact that I accessed a server for my parents website earlier today for the first time.

The error log is giving this message:

```
[Sun Aug 04 09:15:35.889700 2013] [authz_core:error] [pid 5088:tid 1776] [client ::1:58124] AH01630: client denied by server configuration: C:/Users/James/Desktop/Container/XAMPP/apache/icons/folder.gif, referer: http://localhost/Triiline1/
```

I changed this part of the `httpd.conf`, based off of these:

[client denied by server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413042/client-denied-by-server-configuration) and 
[Apache: client denied by server configuration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10351167/apache-client-denied-by-server-configuration)

```
<Directory "C:/Users/James/Desktop/Container/XAMPP/cgi-bin">
    AllowOverride All
    Options None
    Require local
</Directory>
```

I tried `require all granted` and `require local`, no results.

MySQL still functions in XAMPP. How can I fix this?

**UPDATE:**

Several hours later, I open XAMPP, click start, and it works fine. No clue. I am interested if anybody has an explanation or a solution if this happens again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Apache in Xampp will not start if there is another application using port 80.

For example : Skype uses port 80. Therefore when Skype is running Apache will refuse to start since its working port is not available to be registered.

You have mentioned that you tried to access the server from your parents website. How did you do that? Xampp do not allow non local ip's to access its apache server running on local machine / network.

If you want this behavior to be changed, use "Allow All" and remove if any "Deny" parameter is specified in httpd.conf.

Don't forget to save config file. Restart the Apache server to apply the new rule.

Comment: Skype was it! I didn't realize that. Thanks for the info, I never would of figured that out.

Comment: Glad that it helped.. You can change the Skype settings so that it no longer uses port 80. The configuration can be found in connections under settings. Also you can start xampp first and then start Skype. This way there is no conflict as Skype can use other ports.

Comment: I wonder why there are a negative vote , the answer solved the questioners problem and it was right to the point. Negative voters please leave a comment so that I can know what's wrong.. Perhaps improve the answer

Answer (score 1):

1. Open this file: `httpd.conf`
2. Comment this line: `Include conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`
3. Restart the server

Answer (score 0):

Try disabling the other SQL server running in the background.

Go to `services.msc` and find all other SQL servers or server agents and disable them.

Finally, Apache will start.