# Laravel Error HTTP 500 with MAMP

Tags: php, macos, apache, laravel, mamp

I have a Laravel project which works on my Windows. I'm trying to transfer it on my Mac. Unfortunately, I have an Error 500 when I go on my website. When I check apache log I have : client denied by server configuration. Apache is 2.2 version on MAMP.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [client denied by server configuration](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413042/client-denied-by-server-configuration)

Comment: No because all of my others projects in MAMP perfectly work.

Comment: Same issue here. Created laravel on Windows, pushed to git. Now I got an mac from my work. So i clone repo on my mac, but get an error 500 without any other info.

Answer (score 1):

This error means that the access to the directory on the file system was denied by an Apache configuration.

check runner of apache and permissions of directories ...

in installation of laravel :

**Directory Permissions**

After installing Laravel, you may need to configure some permissions. Directories within the storage and the bootstrap/cache directories should be writable by your web server or Laravel will not run. If you are using the Homestead virtual machine, these permissions should already be set.

Comment: Actually I didn't install Laravel on my Mac, I've just transfered the project from my Windows. Should I install Laravel on my Mac ?

Answer (score 1):

Change the chmod of storage and all files inside by -R, and also don't forget to do the same with the bootstrap/cache folder.

```
chmod -R 775 storage
chmod -R 775 bootstrap/cache
```

Check that on "Directory Permissions" in the official laravel documentation installation : https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/installation

Hope that helped. Regards.