# Wordpress - Parts after header won't load

Tags: php, wordpress

This is the web site i am working on: http://eleganceist.com

But unfortunately the sections after head wont load. Error log is full of this:

```
[Fri Sep 28 12:37:48 2018] [error] [client 46.196.24.141] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/eleganceist.com/httpdocs/index.cgi
[Fri Sep 28 12:37:48 2018] [error] [client 46.196.24.141] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/eleganceist.com/httpdocs/index.pl
[Fri Sep 28 12:37:51 2018] [warn] [client 46.196.24.141] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /var/www/vhosts/eleganceist.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/shortcodes.php on line 319
[Fri Sep 28 12:45:52 2018] [error] [client 185.220.101.20] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/eleganceist.com/httpdocs/index.cgi
[Fri Sep 28 12:45:52 2018] [error] [client 185.220.101.20] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/eleganceist.com/httpdocs/index.pl
[Fri Sep 28 12:45:56 2018] [warn] [client 185.220.101.20] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /var/www/vhosts/eleganceist.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/shortcodes.php on line 319
[Fri Sep 28 12:49:14 2018] [error] [client 46.196.24.141] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/eleganceist.com/httpdocs/index.cgi
[Fri Sep 28 12:49:14 2018] [error] [client 46.196.24.141] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/eleganceist.com/httpdocs/index.pl
[Fri Sep 28 12:49:17 2018] [warn] [client 46.196.24.141] mod_fcgid: stderr: PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Error could not be converted to string in /var/www/vhosts/eleganceist.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/shortcodes.php on line 319
[Fri Sep 28 12:49:17 2018] [error] [client 46.196.24.141] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/eleganceist.com/httpdocs/index.cgi
[Fri Sep 28 12:49:17 2018] [error] [client 46.196.24.141] client denied by server configuration: /var/www/vhosts/eleganceist.com/httpdocs/index.pl
```

anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Thank you

Comment: its apache config issue. try to check this link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8413042/client-denied-by-server-configuration/12286673

Answer (score 0):

Check the compatibility with the theme being used by WordPress. Sometimes, when something like home page is built on one theme, and then the website is switched to another theme, the new theme can't identify the layout, and hence the error occurs. Also, check if any sections are disabled in the customizer.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you don't see anything after the error is most likely due to the error you see in the log where a **WP_Error** is attempted to be converted to a **string** and which it doesn't seem to support. It's probably missing a [__toString](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) implementation but more than that it's probably used in an unintended way.

> [Fri Sep 28 12:45:56 2018] [warn] [client 185.220.101.20] mod_fcgid:
>   stderr: PHP Catchable fatal error:  Object of class WP_Error could not
>   be converted to string in
>   /var/www/vhosts/eleganceist.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/shortcodes.php on
>   line 319

This most likely happens somewhere around the header and an [exception](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php) is thrown.
This exception is not caught and thus traverses back up the tree of made function calls in order for some function to handle it and no one does.

Then you seem to have a configuration error also, but since you get "something" when you execute the request the error you seemingly face is more likely related to the PHP error.

You could try to wrap the offending function call in a `try/catch` block and check the status of the **WP_Error** object to see what the original causing error might be.

You might find it's related to the configuration error for instance.

A similar case and an in-depth reply into how to try and locate the error can be found [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/269841/php-catchable-fatal-error-object-of-class-wp-error-could-not-be-converted-to-st).

Answer (score 0):

I think is a compatibilty issue. You need to do debug, you must comment some lines to see what is the reason, and then uncomment. Is there any other version of this theme, the theme is compatible and tested with the version of wp that you have ?

If you can not do debugging use another theme and try to debug to test enviroment.